# What is the difference between FUTEX_WAIT and FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, futex

I have been tracing a process with `strace` and have seen entries such as:

```
futex(0x7ffff79b3e00, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1                                                                
futex(0x7ffff79b3e00, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = 0
```

However, when I looked at the [man page for futex](http://linux.die.net/man/2/futex), I have only seen entries such as `FUTEX_WAIT` and `FUTEX_WAKE`.  So my question is what does `_PRIVATE` that is appended to the end of these names in my `strace` output mean?  For instance is there any difference between something like `FUTEX_WAKE` that is documented in the futex man page and `FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE` that I see in the `strace` output or can I assume that they are the same when I am trying to understand what is happening with the program I am debugging.

Comment: Could it have something to do with [this?](http://lwn.net/Articles/229668/)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is an optimization done by linux/glibc to make futexes faster when they're not shared between processes. Glibc will use the `_PRIVATE` versions of each of the futex calls unless the `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` attribute is set on your mutex

It's explained in more detail here: http://lwn.net/Articles/229668/

For the purposes of your debugging, you can just ignore the `_PRIVATE` suffixes